# Outlook "Inbox" folder renamed to "Untitled"

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2003

I have a strange issue in Outlook I haven't encountered before. I have an Exchange server at home, and when I opened up Outlook today, my "Inbox" folder has been renamed to "Untitled". When I right-click to rename it, that option is disabled.

How can I change the name of my Inbox folder back to "Inbox"? When I search this issue, all I get is articles on how to rename the OST/PST, and not un-renamable folders.

I've got Outlook 2010 and Exchange 2003.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Or are you just a grump?

Comment: I think a good question which is also well worded so +1

Answer (score 1):

I was under the impression you can't rename the default folders, but since you've experienced it then I guess you can.

You could try via VBa

```
Sub InboxRename()
Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set oFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
oFolder.Name = "Inbox"
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

Of course, this won't actually help you to realise who/how/when/why etc but it may get you out of this.

The code above is untested! Back up your emails/calender/contacts etc  first if you have any saved local

[Source](http://www.office-forums.com/threads/outlook-inbox-renamed.194033/)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. When I attempt to run the script, I get a permissions error.